# xml parsing failed using python: xml.etree.cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I download a xml file using

```
wget -O example.xml http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=samsung+mobile&orderby=relevance&start-index=1&max-results=5&v=2
```

I want to get video id, for example, "x_HFR3Hmv44" from  x_HFR3Hmv44
and published time from 2010-10-25T20:42:22.000Z

however, I failed using the following codes

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

sxml = open('example.xml', 'r').read()
tree=et.fromstring(sxml)
for el in tree.findall('published'):
    print el.getchildren()[1].text
```

but I failed,
the output is nothing

can anyone tell me where I'm wrong? thanks!

is it because the xml file can't be processed by xml.etree.cElementTree?
there are tags like , while the yt is not defined in the file

Comment: Failed how? Did you get an error or traceback (please include if so)? What output are you expecting from this code?

Comment: Is this even really your actual code?  It has a typo "exmaple.xml" (incidentally I have an amusing mental image of a trans-species former tree)

Comment: This can't be your code. Your code should output *nothing* since `el.getchildren()` is empty.

Comment: I made a mistake, it is nothing, in my original code, I have an additional print tree

Comment: anyway, how to achieve my goal? how to modify the code? thanks!

Comment: Given that you didn't quote the URL, that can't be your real `wget` line either. If you want us to figure out what's wrong with your code, show us your code—or, better, a stripped down version that can be run and demonstrates exactly the same thing—not something vaguely similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just confused about the XML structure. Add `prettyprint=true` to your query string to get indented xml which will be easier for you to read. Also consult [YouTube's element reference links](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#API_Request_XML_Element_Definitions) to understand what to expect.

This will get you started:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=samsung+mobile&orderby=relevance&start-index=1&max-results=5&v=2'

root = ET.parse(urlopen(url))

def qname(prefix, name, map={'atom':'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}):
    """Helper function for namespaced element names"""
    return '{{{}}}{}'.format(map[prefix], name)


for e in root.findall(qname('atom','entry')):
    print e.findtext(qname('atom','id')), e.findtext(qname('atom','published'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly, but I think you have two problems:

1. `Element.findall()` only finds elements that are direct children of that element, per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements).
2. You need to specify the namespace that this tag belongs to.  For example:

   list(tree.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}published'))

Comment: thanks very much. how to find the namespace? I notice there are namespaces like http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}published, or   http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/, but I can't find them in the xml file